# In XCTest -> Test case method always getting "Errored" in AWS DEVICE FARM

Tags: swift, unit-testing, xctest, aws-device-farm, xctestcase

[image]

Inside XCTest file

```
    func testPerformanceExample() throws {
          XCTAssert(true, "true An unexpected result was encountered")
    }
```

> Command line invocation:
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild test-without-building
> "-only-testing:appTests/testExample"
> -destination id=00008030001458241AFA802E -xctestrun /tmp/scratchR3MYgV.scratch/ProductslujS0V/application.xctestrun
> -derivedDataPath /tmp/derived_data7ShS6_/appTests/testExample
>
> User defaults from command line:
> IDEDerivedDataPathOverride = /tmp/derived_data7ShS6_/appTests/testExample
> IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES
>
> 2023-05-09 07:26:47.436056-0700 app[474:15981]
> Failed to set (layer.cornerRadius) user defined inspected property on
> (NSLayoutConstraint): [<NSLayoutConstraint 0x281ba43c0>
> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant
> for the key layer. Test Suite 'Selected tests' started at 2023-05-09
> 07:26:47.474 Test Suite 'appTests.xctest' started
> at 2023-05-09 07:26:47.475 Test Suite
> 'appTests.xctest' passed at 2023-05-09
> 07:26:47.475.      Executed 0 tests, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in
> 0.000 (0.000) seconds Test Suite 'Selected tests' passed at 2023-05-09 07:26:47.476.   Executed 0 tests, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in
> 0.000 (0.002) seconds 2023-05-09 07:26:47.521 xcodebuild[483:3069] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: 8.822 elapsed -- Testing started
> completed. 2023-05-09 07:26:47.521 xcodebuild[483:3069] [MT]
> IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: 0.000 sec, +0.000 sec -- start
> 2023-05-09 07:26:47.521 xcodebuild[483:3069] [MT]
> IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: 8.822 sec, +8.822 sec -- end
>
> Test session results, code coverage, and logs:
> /tmp/derived_data7ShS6_/appTests/testExample/Logs/Test/Test-Transient
> Testing-2023.05.09_07-26-38--0700.xcresult
>
> ** TEST EXECUTE SUCCEEDED **
>
> Testing started

Comment: is this happening because of include the "XCFramework" in target testproject?